# Standard Deviation Excel from two different lists

Tags: excel, excel-2010, standard-deviation

I am currently trying to find a z score for my values. To start off, I am drawing two separate lists from a different sheet to try to find the standard deviation. Currently I have

```
(G11-(AVERAGE(INDEX('Asia Last Yields'!DU:DU,
MATCH(B3,'Asia Last Yields'!DT:DT)):INDEX('Asia Last Yields'!DU:DU,
MATCH(B1,'Asia Last Yields'!DT:DT)))-AVERAGE(INDEX('Asia Last Yields'!DL:DL,
MATCH(B3,'Asia Last Yields'!DK:DK)):INDEX('Asia Last Yields'!DL:DL,
MATCH(B1,'Asia Last Yields'!DK:DK)))))/(need the standard dev)
```

This is basically ***(original value - mean)*** right now. As you can see it is pretty complicated right now, but basically my problem is since I am drawing from two lists that do not form an array, I cannot simply just use the Standard Deviation function. Is there anyway to combine the two lists without creating a seperate list within the worksheet?

Let me know if I wasn't clear, and thanks for the help!

Comment: unfortunately this didn't work but thanks!

Comment: very difficult to understand this, but I think you'll need to look at something to do with indirect.  If you put the indirect in then you should be able to combine as pnuts has suggested above.   The other way which would be possible, would be through the use of a macro.